# Steel electrical boxes downstream of a 100 amp subpanel

Tags: garage, subpanel, steel

Do steel electrical boxes need to be grounded downstream of an unbonded 100 amp subpanel?

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other. I'm a little concerned with the context of your question. Did you use 3-wire feeder to a sub?  Are you working with pre-1960s ungrounded circuits?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, NEC 314.4.

An unbonded panel is referring to a panel where the ground and neutral aren't bonded together, and separate ground and neutrals are present. The box needs to be connected to that separate ground.

The subpanel and box may be grounded by any method in 250.118, which in addition to using a ground wire includes most continuous metal raceway systems.

If you are unclear if or how your subpanel is properly grounded please feel free to edit your question adding a picture of internals of the subpanel.

Comment: I agree metal boxes need to be grounded and the code references apply. There is 1 group of exceptions that would be prior to the late 60’s when 2 wire branch circuits were code and there was no requirement for grounding anything other than the service.

Answer (score -1):

Would say yes because it keeps the ground path from being broken if in future you remove one outlet/switch from the circuit.

If only grounding switch/outlet, once it is removed, then ground path might be broken for any devices down stream of that switch/outlet, leaving them ungrounded.

Some outlets/switches can be grounded to the box with just the screws holding it to the box.  They do not need to have a ground wire attached.